# Run workflow process from other workflow process

Tags: aem

guys.
I am a newbie in AEM and have a problem.
I need to execute com.day.cq.dam.core.process.UnarchiverProcess process(inherited from AbstractAssetWorkflowProcess) from my own. So I need something like this(code below is obviously not working):

```
import com.day.cq.dam.core.process.UnarchiverProcess;
public class FirstProcess extends AbstractAssetWorkflowProcess {
       public final void execute(final WorkItem item, final WorkflowSession wfSession, final MetaDataMap args)
                throws WorkflowException {
    UnarchiverProcess unarchiverProcess = new UnarchiverProcess();
    unarchiverProcess.execute(item,wfSession,args);
    return;
}
```

Is there any way to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnarchiverProcess` is a standalone process, is there a reason to create a custom step to just invoke `UnarchiverProcess`. 
You could simply add another process step in your workflow model and configure it for `UnarchiverProcess`.

In case you want to do it (I however do not recommend this unless you a have a strong reason for doing it), there are two possibilities -

**First** :

1. Create another custom **workflow model** with just one process step for `UnarchiverProcess`
2. In your process step, use `WorkflowSession` to get `WorkflowModel` (`WorkflowSession.getModel(....)` ) for the above workflow and call `WorkflowSession.startWorkflow(....)` to invoke the process step.

This is not an efficient approach as you are invoking another workflow from a workflow process. Workflows are resource consuming tasks so if this workflow is called on heavy load will cause your instance to slow down.

**Second**:

1. Each workflow process is resitered as an OSGi Service thus can inject other OSGi service.
2. You could inject `UnarchiverProcess` in your custom process. But the challenge is that all the workflow processes are registered via their interface so all the processes are registered as `WorkflowProcess` so you need a way to filter out the only implementation you need i.e. `UnarchiverProcess`

   @Reference(target="(component.name = com.day.cq.dam.core.process.UnarchiverProcess)")
   WorkflowProcess workflowProcess;

Refer to article [here](https://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/set-osgi-service-reference-target-through-configuration/) for more details.

In this approach you are not invoking another process but injecting a service reference and calling its method.

*I would still recommend adding another step to your workflow for this process as its more cleaner approach and you don't need to maintain code just for the sake of it.*

UPDATE :

if Service filtering doesn't work, you can go OSGI Bundle context route (add missing imports) -

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.InvalidSyntaxException;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentFactory;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentInstance;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

/**
 * Created by ameesh.trikha on 2/24/16.
 */

@Service
@Component
public class YourWorkflowClass implements WorkflowProcess {

    private BundleContext bundleContext;
    private Map<String, ServiceReference> serviceReferenceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private Map<String, ComponentInstance> componentInstanceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext context) {
        this.bundleContext = context.getBundleContext();
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext context) {

        synchronized (this.serviceReferenceMap) {
            for(Map.Entry<String,ComponentInstance> componentInstance : this.componentInstanceMap.entrySet()) {
                componentInstance.getValue().dispose();
            }

            for(Map.Entry<String, ServiceReference> serviceReference : this.serviceReferenceMap.entrySet()) {
                this.bundleContext.ungetService(serviceReference.getValue());
            }
        }
        this.componentInstanceMap.clear();
        this.serviceReferenceMap.clear();
        this.bundleContext = null;
    }


    public UnarchiverProcess getUnarchiverProcess() {

        ServiceReference [] serviceReferences;

        String serviceIdentifier = "component.name="+UnarchiverProcess.class.getName();
        if (this.componentInstanceMap.containsKey(serviceIdentifier)) {
            final ComponentInstance componentInstance = this.componentInstanceMap.get(serviceIdentifier);
            return (UnarchiverProcess) componentInstance.getInstance();
        }

        try {
            serviceReferences = this.bundleContext.getServiceReferences(ComponentFactory.class.getName(), serviceIdentifier);
        } catch (InvalidSyntaxException ise) {

            LOGGER.error("Could'nt get Service reference for {}", serviceIdentifier, ise);
            return null;
        }

        if (null != serviceReferences && serviceReferences.length > 0) {
            final ServiceReference serviceReference = serviceReferences[0];
            final ComponentFactory componentFactory = (ComponentFactory) this.bundleContext.getService(serviceReference);
            final ComponentInstance componentInstance = componentFactory.newInstance(null);
            final UnarchiverProcess unarchiverProcess = (UnarchiverProcess) componentInstance.getInstance();
            if (unarchiverProcess == null) {
                LOGGER.error("Unable to get " + serviceIdentifier);
                componentInstance.dispose();
                this.bundleContext.ungetService(serviceReference);
            } else {
                synchronized (this.serviceReferenceMap) {
                    this.serviceReferenceMap.put(serviceIdentifier, serviceReference);
                    this.componentInstanceMap.put(serviceIdentifier, componentInstance);
                }
            }

            return unarchiverProcess;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, I really need to do it the way I described. I already tried your second solution, but  I got this when trying to upload bundle on my Process.: Reference workflowProcess ["Unsatisfied","Service Name: com.day.cq.workflow.exec.WorkflowProcess","Target Filter: (component.name = com.day.cq.dam.core.process.UnarchiverProcess)","Cardinality: 1..1","Policy: static","Policy Option: reluctant","No Services bound"]  I think the reason is that UnarchiverProcess is absent in OSGI, but some other WorkflowProcess  implementations are present there I dunno why.

Comment: Can you remove the space between = in target and try i.e. `component.name=com.day.cq.dam.core.process.UnarchiverProcess`